# Problem Listing files in bash with spaces in directory path

Tags: bash, command-line, ls

When entered directory into the command line, this:

```
ls -d -1 "/Volumes/Development/My Project/Project"/**/* | grep \.png$
```

Prints a list of all the file ending in `.png`.

However when I try and create a script:

```
#! /bin/bash

clear ;

# Tempoary dir for processing
mkdir /tmp/ScriptOutput/ ;

wdir="/Volumes/Development/My Project/Project" ;

echo "Working Dir: $wdir" ;

# Get every .PNG file in the project
for image in `ls -d -1 "$wdir"/**/* | grep \.png$`; do
...    
done
```

I get the error:

```
cp: /Volumes/Development/My: No such file or directory
```

The <kbd>space</kbd> is causing an issue, but I don't know why?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to change IFS:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"  # save it
IFS="" # don't split on any white space
for file in `ls -R . | grep png`
do 
    echo "$file"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS # restore IFS
```

Read more about IFS in `man bash`.

Answer (score 2):

[Use more quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) and [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
for image in "$wdir"/**/*.png; do
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fine with using `while read` and subprocess created by pipe, you can:

```
find . -name '*.png' | while read FILE
do 
    echo "the File is [$FILE]"
done
```

Comment: You could even `'find . -name '*.png' -exec echo {} \;'`.  The -exec option to find can be used many times if needed.

Comment: Right - for one command (like echo here) it's best to use -exec (or |xargs for better performance if there are many files). For more than one command I prefer to while loop. It's easier to read for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try, [[:space:]] in place of space

```
wdir="/Volumes/Development/My[[:space:]]Project/Project"
```

or execute command to convert single space

```
wdir=`echo "$wdir" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/\[[:space:]]/g'`
```